# Convert "43961529(10%)" to "43,961,529.00 (10%)" in C#?

Tags: c#

How can I convert `43961529(10%)` to `43,961,529.00` in C#?

I have the value `43961529(10%)` in one `DataTable`'s `DataColumn` and I want to convert this to `43,961,529.00 (10%)`.

Between the brackets (`(10%)`) is the market share.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008, C#.

Comment: What have you tried already? - show the code you have and how it isn't working.

Comment: Do you have it as a string? Then you need to parse the string by splitting the value and market share into two two strings and parsing those strings to numbers, then you need to format the result to a new string as per SpaceApples answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a *regular expression* you can get the numeric part out of the string. Then you can parse it as an integer, format it any way you like, and put the string back together again.

```
public static string Format(string input)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(\d+)(.*)$");
    var match = regex.Match(input);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        input = Int32.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value).ToString("N2");
        input += " " + match.Groups[2].Value;
    }
    return input;
}
```

You use it like this:

```
string input = "43961529(10%)";
string result = Format(input);      // "43,961,529.00 (10%)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the ToString() overrides

```
decimal num = 43961529;
string val = num.ToSTring("N2");
```

or

```
string val = num.ToSTring("0.00");
```

There are many ways to sort the output of a string